# Using JMP instead of CALLS

Tags: assembly, keil

Can a JMP instruction be used to jump to the start address of a function, and why would one do so?

Comment: A call can return where the call originated, a jump can not.  You cannot implement a procedural program that uses functions with jumps.

Comment: I see. It's clear now. Thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: You can use `JMP` to jump to the start of a function, it's typically used for _tail call optimization_.

Comment: Thanks for the term. Searched it up.

Comment: @HansPassant: I edited the question to delete the invalid part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prinziple you can mix jmp and calls as long as you follow the rules. `call` pushes the return address on the stack automatically.

```
 call x
 mov eax, 0   <-  returns here

x:
  do something
  ret
```

This could be done as well by the fowlloing code:

```
 jmp x
 :retAdr
 mov eax, 0   <-  returns here

x:
   do something
    push retAdr    <- Basically it would be similar to a jmp, but of course the target can be calculated as well.
   ret
```

And of course you can do it the other way around as well.

```
call x
mov eax, 0

x:
   pop eax  <- ret adress
   do something
   jmp eax
```

While these pseudocode samples may not look usefull, simetimes it may be usefull to use them this way in special cases. The target of a `jmp` can be any address, so it can also be a function or procedure. There is no difference here.

I have seen this used in ant-debugging techniques to obscure the return path and make reversing harder. It can also be used for jmp tables or other stuff. I used a jmp to a function, when I redericted an existing function somewhere else, and then forward the code to the originall function afterwards (injecting code).

Comment: Almost exactly what I'm looking for. So, rets can be used for jumps as long as the return address is on top of the stack. Thank you.

Comment: What you need to consider though is, the size of the return address. Usually this would be a 32 bit value, but of course, it can be 48 bits as well if it is a long jump including the segment. Normally the compiler/assembler knows this, but if you meddle with this manually, it might cause an issue if you use the wrong size.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I can't go to a different segment using RETS. I could use two registers to store the return address and then use JMP instead.

Comment: The same rules apply always. In case of segments being included, you just have to use the appropriate instructions or stack setup. In normal 32 bit code you shouldn't have to deal with that though as it usually uses a flat memory model.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I might be transferring control to another segment so I might have to take note of that.

Answer (score 2):

The most common example of this is tail call optimization as mentioned by Jester, usually when the intermediate functions don't return a value or if the return value is ignored by the initial caller. Example as coded:

```
        call    x
;       ...
x:
;       ...
        call    y
        ret
```

gets optimized to:

```
        call    x
;       ...
x:
;       ...
        jmp     y
```

Comment: Thanks. So, in the **second** case, the function y will never return right? Because if it does, then there must be a push instruction before the RETS command so that the next instruction from x's caller will execute correctly -> resulting to no optimization at all.

Comment: The sequence is a call to x (which pushes the return address onto the stack), jump to y, and y will return to the location just after the call to x.

Comment: I see, so in there, there will only be one return address pushed to/popped out of the stack. Thanks.